# Is there a way how to instruct compiler not to create internal class for anonymous delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous

Let's have following example (please note that the reason why the members are static is purely because I wanted it to be as short as possible and runnable):

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly ReaderWriterLock Lock = new ReaderWriterLock();

    public static void SafeRead(Action action)
    {
        Lock.AcquireReaderLock(1000);

        try
        {
            action();
        }
        finally
        {
            Lock.ReleaseReaderLock();
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SafeRead(() => Console.WriteLine(args));
    }
}
```

After viewing it in the ILSpy I can see that an internal class "c__DisplayClass2_0" is created for the lambda. The class contains the method and reference to local variable "args" stored in public field as seen here:

```
.class nested private auto ansi sealed beforefieldinit '<>c__DisplayClass2_0'
extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    // Fields
    .field public string[] args

    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {} // end of method '<>c__DisplayClass2_0'::.ctor

    .method assembly hidebysig 
        instance void '<Main>b__0' () cil managed 
    {} // end of method '<>c__DisplayClass2_0'::'<Main>b__0'

} // end of class <>c__DisplayClass2_0
```

I understand that the class and the field is needed in case the lambda comes out of lifetime of the args local variable and Main method itself. But what if I can assure that the lambda is called synchronously within the Main method as in my example? Probably it would be enough to create an internal field and a method within the Program class, not creating an extra class. I am aware of the fact that the size of the Program class will increase by this internal field, but if any method containing such anonymous delegates is called very frequently, every single call creates an extra class which seems to me worse case if I prefer performance over memory consumption.. Is there a way how to instruct compiler not to create internal classes in my scenario? Or am I missing something important?

Comment: It is **exceptionally** unlikely that this implementation detail will ever by the root cause of any performance issues in a real program. It's an implementation detail of the compiler and it will generate classes for all kinds of reasons.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that, **in general**, any method may be called by multiple threads simultaneously. With your "just keep a local field" approach, what happens when the second caller to `Main` passes a different value for `args` whilst the first caller's call is still running and hasn't consumed it yet?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well, it reminds me situation with foreach.. Once I created a system where many foreach loops happend within one method. Since this method was called many times per second, it created hundreds of thousands of enumerator classes. Then garbage collector had a big impact on the performance. After replacing with "for" loops it became much better.

Comment: but I bet you focussed your attention there *when it was a performance bottleneck and not meeting performance goals*. Did it then mean that you *never* use `foreach` now or do you still use it in most common usage scenarios?

Comment: The whole reason for this extra class is to bundle up all the closed-over variables into a persistent object. If you're not using closure then there's no reason to use anonymous delegates (i.e. you can directly reference class methods instead), and you'll no longer have a proliferation of "hidden" classes. All in all, probably a lesson in pointless micro-optimisation.

Comment: I call shenanigans, do you have a gc or performance problem?

Comment: @TheGeneral If GC stops your threads because of collecting, then you have performance problem ;)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree with you that it doesn't make sense to micro-optimize before it is really needed, I just wanted to know if there are some hidden features that I am not aware of. In case I encounter performance problem in future, I wanted to know whether there is a solution or not.. Thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, don't use lambda expressions:

```
private static string[] args;
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program.args = args;
    SafeRead(Write);
}

private static void Write()
{
    Console.WriteLine(args);
}
```

This code will not generate the intermediate class for your lambda expression with the arguments.

You can also make the action a `Action<string[]>` and pass along the arguments to and from `SafeRead`.

Comment: But as I realised, and as a general point, you cannot use this strategy if you expect `Main` to be called by multiple threads.

Comment: See the update of passing the arguments along to `SafeRead` @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: :) well, in your case I need to declare the private static args.. That's what I wanted to avoid. Maybe I wasn't very clear, I was wondering if I can get closer to, let's say, #define C++ behaviour.. Anyway, I really appreciate all you replies, guys. Thank you!

Comment: The generated class is a direct consequence of using the lambda. So, no, there is no other way to force the compiler to compile differently @Rexxowski

Comment: @PatrickHofman -- So, no, there is no other way to force the compiler to compile differently. -- That's exactly what I wanted to know.. Thanks..

Comment: No, not documented as far as I know @Rexxowski